# IntelliJ IDEA unable to build Java -source 8 project via Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 and I am getting the message:

*"default methods are not supported in -source 7"*

and that I may use:

"*-source 8 or higher" when I'm building my project via Gradle."*

I have ensure that the Project SDK is at least 1.8 and project language level is 8 in every module in the Project Structure.

Java compiler Javac is working with project bytecode version 8.

What could I be missing? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using gradle or maven check maven.compiler.target

Comment: "I'm building my project via Gradle". Update Gradle.

Comment: Try running the build in Gradle on the command line to make it clear if it is an IntelliJ or Gradle issue. If it is Gradle, then look in your build files and search for  `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility`. Looks like you might have them configured to 1.7.

Comment: Paul Whelan: I have no idea what maven.compiler.target is or where I can find it.

Peter: Don't know what that means.

Bjorn Vester: I found sourceCompatibility in build.gradle (did you mean that with "files"?) and its set to 1.7. But if I change it manually to 1.8 I get a different error: "Required org.gradle.jvm.version '7' and found incompatible value '8'."

Comment: The `maven.compiler.target` thing is a Maven option that you can ignore as you are using Gradle. By "build files", I meant the files called `*.gradle` (e.g. `build.gradle`). You need to set `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to 1.8 in _all_ projects. Alternatively, remove them entirely and rely on defaults. You can't have a project set to 1.7 that depends on one that uses 1.8.